# VSCode Prettier on Save on any projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this block of code in VS Code

Note:

> 1 - My double quotes are `"`

> 2 - My semicolon locate at end of lines

> 3 - My indentation is messed up, and I like to use tab with 4 spaces

```
...
modal.find("#portfolio-title").text(title);
    modal.find("#portfolio-tag").html(tags);
...
```

I would like to configure my VSCode to run a [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) onsave.

When I hit save, nothing happened, what else do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with these steps

1 - install [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

2 - create `.prettierrc`

More [settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#settings)

```
{
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "printWidth": 160,
    "tabWidth": 10
}
```

3 - Update VS Code Settings, **settings.json**

***Note :*** To modify as json click on this button.

[image]

```
...
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.vueIndentScriptAndStyle": true,
"prettier.useTabs": true,
"prettier.configPath": "/Users/alpha/Sites/notes/VSCode/.prettierrc",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

4 - onSave

on any projects, your prettier settings (.prettierrc) above will kick in.

[image]

## 5 - done